# Golang tutorial's slices exercise - my code does not work if index&value iteration is used

Tags: go

I'm doing golang tutorial, and the [very first exercise](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/18) is giving me a headache.

The exercise in a nutshell wants me to dynamically create a array with dx*dy dimention.

This is my function that receives `dx`, `dy` and returns `[dx][dy]uint8` array that works:

```golang
func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    resultArray := make([][]uint8, dx, dx)
    for i := range resultArray {
        fmt.Println(resultArray[i])
        resultArray[i] = make([]uint8, dy, dy)
        fmt.Println(resultArray)
        for j := range resultArray[i] {
            if (i+j)%30 <= 15 {
                resultArray[i][j] = uint8(255)
            }
        }
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

However, this code which uses `for i, v := range x` does **not** work:

```golang
func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    resultArray := make([][]uint8, dx, dx)
    for i, ithRow := range resultArray {
        ithRow = make([]uint8, dy, dy)
        for j := range ithRow {
            if (i+j)%30 <= 15 {
                ithRow[j] = uint8(255)
            }
        }
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

Does this not work because `ithRow` is a copy of `resultArray[i]`, but not reference of it? If so, why is it not reference of it(like, what is the benefit or use case of making it copied)?

Comment: *"Does this not work because ithRow is a copy of resultArray[i], but not reference of it?"* Yes. *"If so, why is it not reference of it"* Because in Go **everything** is pass-by-value.

Comment: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/29/there-is-no-pass-by-reference-in-go

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you, before that point the tutorial did not mention about what golang's calling/iterating convention used. However I still don't know why in the world I mistakenly thought it would be similar to C++'s pass-by-reference-ish calling convention (`function(type & arg)`).